# Prepositions for use with engagement

Tags: grammar

If an *engagement* is **with** an object, is a *disengagement* also **with** the object, or is it **from** an object?

Comment: You go *to* a place, but come *from* a place.

Comment: This seems a very legitimate question to me; why the down votes? [I'm finding people strikingly unfriendly on this site. Got to love the internet!]

Comment: [disengage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disengage?q=disengage) goes with *from* (ODO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disengages *from* someone or something.

[disengage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disengage): to **separate from** someone or something; withdraw

One doesn't separate *with*, one separates *from*. However, since the word has "from" in it's definition, sometimes the *from* is understood, and need not be stated.

> The two dancers moved together in a series of quick movements before *disengaging* and leaping apart.

It's understood that the dancers are disengaging *from* each other and separating.

> If there is a malfunction, the gears will automatically disengage.